# Not able to store data in database in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iphone programming.Iam using Mac 10.7.3 in that i am not able to store data in database I am storing data inside database through textfield.Can any body tell me why its not adding data inside the database.What is mistake in this code

```
 NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
// Get the documents directory
dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
// Build the path to the database file
    databasePath =  [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test.db"];
    NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
    NSFileManager *fn=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    BOOL success=[fn fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(!success) {

NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
success = [fn copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
    }
    //NSLog(@"sdasdassd%@",databasePath);
    NSLog(@"hai");
    sqlite3_stmt  *statement;

    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];
            if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSLog(@"hai2");
 NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into path(imagepath,audiopath) values (\"%@\",\"%@\")",name.text,email.text];

            const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

            sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);
            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
            {
                    NSLog(@"details added");    

            } else {
                    NSLog(@"details not added");    
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
            sqlite3_close(contactDB);

        }
    }
```

Thanks
Aslam

Comment: did u check in library -> simulator -> applications -> app -> document -> sqlite database? check whether table and fields are created or not.?

Comment: Most likely you failed to report any errors.

Comment: errors or not coming.In console its displaying that details not add

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when application load, then copy database into application folder

App Delegate file's Code ::

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

      NSString *docsDir;
      NSArray *dirPaths;

      // Get the documents directory
      dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
      docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

      //Build the path to the database file
      databasePath =  [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"test.db"];
      NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);

      NSFileManager *fn=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
      NSError *error;

      BOOL success=[fn fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

      if(!success) {

          NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.db"];
          success = [fn copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
      }
}
```

Then, on Save Button Click,

here, `[app dbpath]` is NSString accessed from delegate file.

Code ::

```
 sqlite3_stmt  *statement;

 const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

 if (sqlite3_open([[app dbpath] UTF8String], &contactDB) == SQLITE_OK) {
 {
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"insert into path(imagepath,audiopath) values (\"%@\",\"%@\")",name.text,email.text];

    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSLog(@"details added");

    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"details not added");
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(contactDB);
}
```

It may be help to you.
Thanks.

Comment: thanks for giving replay.[app dbpath] here its showing some error

Comment: can u tell me why its not storing data inside the database

Comment: did u check database which is created in simulator folder. Is that same as you created in application ?

Comment: check tables as well as fields in the table